# Remove line between caption and table

Tags: tables, captions, rules

How I can remove line between caption and table?

My code is:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\tables{360pt}{1.875pt}
\caption{EG unit Characteristics for TPC and 201 bus distribution systems}
\label{tab1} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccccccccc@{}}
\tchrule
System & EGparameters &EG1 & EG2 & EG3 & EG4 & EG5 & EG6 & EG7 & EG8 & EG9 & EG10 & EG11 & EG12 & EG13 & EG14 & EG15\\ 
\tbrule
 & Type & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
TPC & Location & 4 & 65 & 25 & 35 & 84 & 55 & 12 & 72 & 20 & 47 & 11 & 60 & 41 &    30 & 76\\ 
 & Capacity & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\tbrule
 & Type & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
201 & Location & 3 & 26 & 177 & 18 & 64 & 74 & 144 & 98 & 200 & 137 & 135 & 57 & 16 &   128 & 113\\ 
 & Capacity & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\ 
\tbrule
Type & \multicolumn{16}{c}{1:Combined Cycle Gas Turbine 2:Combined Cycle Gas Turbine 3:Combined Cycle Gas Turbine}\\
\tbrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I used `\nocaptionrule` but it gave error:! Undefined control sequence. \caption rule.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how (or in which package) the macros `\tbrule` and `\tchrule` are defined.

Comment: \def\tchrule{\noalign{\vskip3pt\hrule depth .15pt\vskip4.75pt}}

Comment: \def\tbrule{\noalign{\vskip2.75pt\hrule depth .5pt\vskip1.5pt}}

Comment: And what about the `\tables` command? Seems like you can just remove `\tchrule` if your `\caption` is above the table. ;)

Comment: in that case the line under caption not covering complete table

Comment: I thought you wanted to get rid of the line entirely. Is that not the case?

Comment: Please do share with us how the `\tables` macro is defined.

Comment: tables
\leftskip=\dimen0}
%
\def\ttrule{\vskip-4.5pt\rule{\dimen10}{.85pt}\vskip4.25pt}
\def\tshrule{\noalign{\vskip3.5pt\hrule depth .15pt\vskip5.25pt}}
\def\acline{\noalign{\vskip3.5pt}}
\def\bcline{\noalign{\vskip5.75pt}}
\def\tchrule{\noalign{\vskip3pt\hrule depth .15pt\vskip4.75pt}}
\def\tintrule{\noalign{\vskip3pt\hrule depth .15pt\vskip4.75pt}}
\def\tbrule{\noalign{\vskip2.75pt\hrule depth .5pt\vskip1.5pt}}
%\def\csone#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\def\csone#1{\qm{#1}\qm}
\def\cs#1#2#3{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\csfix{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}
%

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding code snippets in comments, that is more convenient. The best thing would be if you added a complete example with the necessary packages and definitions, so that it could be copied and compiled without any modifications.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}clccccccccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
System & EGparameters &EG1 & EG2 & EG3 & EG4 & EG5 & EG6 & EG7 & EG8 & EG9 & EG10 & EG11 & EG12 & EG13 & EG14 & EG15\\ 
\midrule
& Type & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
TPC & Location & 4 & 65 & 25 & 35 & 84 & 55 & 12 & 72 & 20 & 47 & 11 & 60 & 41 &    30 & 76\\ 
& Capacity & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\midrule
& Type & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
201 & Location & 3 & 26 & 177 & 18 & 64 & 74 & 144 & 98 & 200 & 137 & 135 & 57 & 16 &   128 & 113\\ 
& Capacity & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\ 
\midrule
Type & \multicolumn{16}{c}{1:Combined Cycle Gas Turbine 2:Combined Cycle Gas Turbine 3:Combined Cycle Gas Turbine}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{EG unit Characteristics for TPC and 201 bus distribution systems}
\label{tab1}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```